# Binding computations with the State monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm looking to pass a State monad through the following functions:

```
e1 :: Int -> (Bool, Int)
e1 el 
  | el > 100           = (True, el)
  | otherwise          = (False, 0)

e2 :: Int -> (Bool, Int)
e2 el 
  | el > 200           = (True, el)
  | otherwise          = (False, 0)

e3 :: Int -> (Bool, Int)
e3 el 
  | el > 300           = (True, el)
  | otherwise          == (False, 0)

implementor :: State Bool Int
implementor = state e1 ...

main = do 
  print $ runState implementor 10
```

Currently `runState` is passed an `State s a` (`implementor`) and a value (10), and then returning the tuple from `e1`.

However I'd like to bind these operations together, such as:

```
state e1 >>= e2 >>= e3
```

`e1` would pass its `State Bool Int` to `e2`, which would operate on the `Int` (through `el`), then pass it's resulting `State Bool Int` to `e3` which, again, would operate on the `Int` in this incoming State.

I've found the instance of Monad State very confusing, following [this](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/) guide:

```
instance Monad (State s) where
   return :: state $ \s -> (s, a)--this is returning a State which contains function (s -> (s, a))
   m >>= k = state $ \s -> let (a, s') = runState m s --? 
                     in runState (k a) s'
```

I don't understand what this instance of bind is doing and how to use this to bind `e1`, `e2` and `e3` together?

Comment: Are you looking for `state e1 >> state e2 >> state e3`?

Comment: @Zeta I've added to my question for clarity

Comment: Err, `state e1` is __not__ a `State Bool Int`, but a `State Int Bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a` on `e1`, you end up with a `State Int Bool`:

```
state e1 :: State Int Bool
```

That is something that acts over a state (in this case an `Int`) and yields a `Bool` as a result of using that state. So if we want to use `e1`, `e2` and `e3` after each other in a stateful computation, we could use them with `do`-notation:

```
allThree :: State Int ()
allThree = do
  firstBool  <- state e1
  secondBool <- state e2
  thirdBool  <- state e3
  return thirdBool
```

However, if we ignore the first two `Bool`s, we can just remove the bindings:

```
allThree :: State Int Bool
allThree = do
  state e1
  state e2
  state e3
```

And now we can rewrite `do`-notation with `>>` and `>>=`. We end up with

```
allThree :: State Int Bool
allThree = state e1 >> state e2 >> state e3
```

As for how this works, let's have a look at `>>=`

```
  m >>= k = state $ \s -> let (a, s') = runState m s 
                          in runState (k a)
```

And `m >> k` is `m >>= const k`. So let's check what `state e1 >> state 2` does:

```
 state e1 >> state e2 
   = state e1 >>= const (state e2)
   = state $ \s -> let (a, s') = runState (state e1) s in runState (const (state e2) a) s'
     -- simplify runState (state e1) s to e1 s
   = state $ \s -> let (a, s') = e1 s in runState (const (state e2) a) s'
     -- use "const"
   = state $ \s -> let (a, s') = e1 s in runState (state e2) s'
     -- again simplify runState (state e2) s' to e2 s'
   = state $ \s -> let (a, s') = e1 s in e2 s'
```

Therefore, the following terms are the same:

```
stateful  s = runState (state e1 >> state e2) s -- use above to show that
stateless s = let (_, s') = e1 s 
              in e2 s'
```

Now, why was I able to use change `runState (state f)` to `f`? Because the definition of `State` is rather boring:

```
-- simplified, modern versions use a more sophisticated approach!
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

That is, a `State`ful action is something that takes a state and returns a new one along to the value. The `state` function is thus rather simple:

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
state = State
```

And since `runState (State f)` is `f`, `runState (state f)` is also `f´.

Therefore, we could write the `Monad` instance a little bit different:

```
instance Monad (State s) where
  (State e1) >>= f = State e3
     where  
       e3 s = let (a, s')    = e s
                  (State e2) = f a
              in e2 s'
```

Remember, `>>=` expects a function that takes something and returns another action, whereas the  `>>` can be used to chain actions after each other.